# Strcpy from char* to char[] creating the wrong form

Tags: c, string

```
typedef struct Symbol{
    char varName[16];
} Symbol;

...............
Symbol *newSymbol = malloc(sizeof(Symbol));
const char space[2] = " ";


char *String = "Name Test";

//break off the first word from String and put it into name

char *name;
name = strtok(String,space);

//convert the char * to char[16]

char nameArray[16];
strcpy(nameArray,name);

//set newSymbol->varName to the newly created char[16]

newSymbol->varName = nameArray
```

I have a `char *` called `String`. In my actual program, it is read from a file using `fgets`, I am just calling it "Name Test" for the purposes of this example. I want to take the first word of the string and assign it as the `varName` in a `Symbol`. So what should happen is `newSymbol->varName` is set to "Name". Because `strtok` returns a `char *` but I need a `char[16]` for the struct, I must convert the `char *` to a `char[16]`.

However, I get this error:

```
"Error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[16]' from type 'char*' 
newSymbol -> varName = nameArray;
```

So,  it seems like strcpy it not actually converting the `char *` to a `char[16]`. Even after declaring a `char[16]` and telling `strcpy` to put the contents of the `char *` into it, I still have a `char *` instead of a `char[16]`. I need to make it work without changing the struct, so that is not an option here.

How can I convert a `char *` into a `char[16]`?

Comment: Hmmm `char *String = "Name Test"; ... name = strtok(String,space);` looks iffy, trying to change a string literal  I think.

Comment: You're quite right, @chux, but I take that to be an error the OP introduced in the process of reducing his original code to the example he presented.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign the contents of an array using the regular assignment operator in C.

You can use `strcpy` for strings and `memcpy/memset` for other data types. (You could use `memcpy/memset` for strings too but `strcpy` is simpler)

Instead of

```
newSymbol -> varName = nameArray;
```

use

```
strcpy(newSymbol -> varName, nameArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, it seems like strcpy it not actually converting the char* to a char[16].

No, the problem is that C does not provide for assigning to (whole) arrays.  `newSymbol->varName` is an array of 16 `char`.  You can assign to *elements* of that array, and you can copy into it with `strcpy()` or a similar function, but you cannot assign to the whole array.

In your particular code, I'd dispense with variable `nameArray`, changing this ...

```
strcpy(nameArray,name);
```

... to this:

```
strcpy(newSymbol->varName, name);
```

(Or perhaps to a similar usage of `strncpy()`, to protect from overrunning the array bounds.)